# writing spec for seeds.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, seed

In a project, the `seeds.rb` is getting complicated. We have a `seeds/` directory with yml files containing data to be loaded. It should work on re-runs and it should not duplicate records (this is allowed in model). Well, the seeds.rb should be tested, it is used to update production. I'm not getting my head around this one though, wondering wether or not to move the logic to `lib/` and write specs as normal. What would you do?

rails 3 with rspec.

Comment: It seems odd to be using seeds.db for updates, wouldn't migrations be more suitable? I'd have thought that seeds.db would only be used for the first-time deployment.

Comment: I second Andy and normal migrations are a better way to update your data in production.

Comment: So you would have generate migrations that don't change the schema at all? How would you do that? Using your models in migrations is an anti-pattern. They don't allow the model to change, unless you refactor old migrations too, which also is an anti-pattern. Please, if I get this wrong, write an answer describing the process. I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should try out the seed-fu gem:
https://github.com/mbleigh/seed-fu

It doesn't generate duplicate records and can help maintain the consistency of the data.